# Copy excel rows programatically with column widths

Tags: c#, excel

hope someone can help. i have an excel workbook and in that i have several sheets.

what i want to do is get row 1 from sheet named "Sheet1" and paste it into several other sheets (not all). Also, i want to maintain the column widths of row 1 from sheet 1 while copying, this is actually very important.

i mention several other sheets because i would like exclude some sheets, which i am planning to store in a list.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = null;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = null;
Excel.Sheets xlSheets = null;
Excel.Worksheet xlNewSheet = null;
```

any ideas how this can be done in c#?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining the width of a column or a row is very difficult to do. In my opinion: first copy the data, then read the width values of the old columns and apply them to the new columns.
All other solutions which I have seen rely on pastespecial and sometimes do not work.